# 2 promises run simultaneously when 'return' is not used

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

If I perform an async operation in JS and I chain 2 `.then` calls, when I use the return keyword on the async operation in the first `.then` the execution happens as expected:

1. first async operation executes after x amount of time
2. second async operation executes after x amount of time

but, if the async operation in the first `.then` doesn't explicitly use `return`, both operations complete at the same time, x amount of time after the initial async operation, example:

scenario 1:

```js
function doAsync() {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => res('hi'), 3000);
  });
}

doAsync().then(() => {
  console.log('async then 1'); // executes 3 seconds after 
  return doAsync();
}).then(() => {
  console.log('async then 2'); // executes 6 seconds after
});
```

scenario 2:

```js
function doAsync() {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => res('hi'), 3000);
  });
}

doAsync().then(() => {
  console.log('async then 1'); // executes 3 seconds after 
  doAsync(); // no return
}).then(() => {
  console.log('async then 2'); // executes 3 seconds after
});
```

why is this? does `return` signify to wait for the first promise to resolve before moving on to the second promise? so if return is skipped, the second async operation starts before waiting for the first promise to resolve?

Comment: `does return signify to wait for the first promise to resolve` - not really ... because `doAsync` returns a promise, the promise returned by .then "takes on" the value of `doAsync` ... therefore won't resolve until that promise resolves

Comment: You may want to read the documentation about [Promise Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining)

Comment: or read the promise resolution procedure at https://promisesaplus.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you omit the `return` keyword the second `doAsync()` gets scheduled immediately and the first `then` exits.

You are not chaining your Promises if you omit the `return` keyword.

Comment: do you have a reference for this so I can confirm? because what you're describing is  the behavior I'm seeing

Comment: @duxfox-- I linked the documentation that covers this exact behavior in my comment...

Comment: can you point to where exactly, because I read the docs and didnt see the same exact scenario - i read the section titled 'timing'